# perl calling 'ssh -f -N' .. should I use Net::Expect, system or exec?

Tags: perl, ssh, expect

I'm trying to automate a process with perl that will basically telnet into one system, "ssh -f -N" into two more and finally open a screen/tmux session and run sshuttle, then disconnect from screen/tmux.

If I am going to be running ssh with the "-f -N" options - is this best handled through Net::SSH::Expect, Net::Expect, system or exec?

I'm concerned with Net::SSH or Net::Expect as I'm not sure of a few things, first, how can I get Net::Expect/SSH to recognize that the SSH session is successful?  That is to say, when I program Net::Expect and spawn the ssh session with those parameters, and subsequently login, there is no more output for 'expect' to see.  I'd like to rely upon something other than the expect timeout.

Does that make sense?  I'm not sure I'm phrasing my question clearly.

I'm also not sure how perl will behave if I spawn the ssh session that goes into the background.  Will my perl program never exit?  Waiting for the backgrounded SSH sessions to end?

It is because of this last question that I ask the additional questions of whether I should be considering the use of system or exec calls over `Net::Expect`.

Comment: Does the perl code do any other processing aside from running the external commands? This sounds better suited to a shell script than a perl script.

Comment: The code does not do much other than run external commands.  I would typically use a shell script for this, but needed something like expect to pass the passwords to ssh.  That, along with trying to learn more perl, is why I am trying to use Net::Expect.

Comment: and these particular hosts do not allow me to use rsa keys for passwordless login.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), which can integrate with Expect if needed.

Edit, Ugh, I missed that you were relaying it through a telnet session. Ignore the above.

Comment: So how could I automate a couple of SSH sessions w/o using RSA keys that would also somehow survive the initial script upon exit?
    
I can't use shell scripting w/o RSA keys, as far as I'm aware, as I don't know how to pass the passwords to the SSH login prompts.
    
I can't seem to use perl Expect as it hard_closes the ssh sessions when the perl script ends.  I suspect that the real TCL based expect would do  the same.